# Cannot store load test results in a TFS 2005 results store

Tags: visual-studio-2005, tfs, load-testing

I've setup a results store and when I publish results of a load test, I can't view the published test details.

From the test run section of the build report I click on the published build and when I choose View Test Results Details from the Test Runs shortcut menu I get an error that the test results details cannot be viewed because the results were not stored in a results store.

I've looked for the data in the results store database and I don't anything there so the error makes sense.

I've setup a connection string to the results store in the Administer Test Controller dialog. Is this the only thing that needs to be done to get test results into the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reports aren't going to be available until after the data has been copied to the data warehouse.  This can typically take up to one hour to do.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404692(VS.80).aspx

Comment: I would assume that before it can be added to the data warehouse it has to be added to the results store. jMM